# Should I generate a temporary password or just send a reset link for legacy users?

Tags: django, authentication

A few months ago I started a side project which has garnered around 3-4k users now. I have been making do with spreadsheets so far, but now I'm making a Django app and transferring their data into the database. So, so far, none of the users really have a username or password.

I am thinking about what the best way to let them log in and view their data would be. I could either

- generate random passwords and email them, and once they log in with the randomly generated password, they can change their password
- just email them a password reset link.

I think the second option would be much easier. Is there a functional difference between the two options? Is there a better way I can handle this?

Comment: second option is secured, the first not. You can't secure a password sent by mail

Comment: @AviahLaor: And how is the reset link secured? Or does it not need to be secured? What is the difference between the reset link and a one-time password that has to be changed immediately after login?

Comment: I'd go for the second approach, if only because you are going to need a password reset function anyway.

Comment: Nothing is 100%, but it's better: (1) Only the person that enters the password knows it, where in email it's explicit, (2) you usually limit the link to 24h, so if somebody grab that link afterwords, it's useless. True, in the first 24h somebody can grab it, but it's better than password that is stored on mail servers forever. If you do want to use password, just make sure that the site enforces the user first step to change password before she sees any data

Comment: I'd go with a third option and send them an email telling them to reset their password, don't include the link. Then they can come to your site, enter their email, and have a reset link sent to them. (Generate random passwords upon initial db insertion so no one can get in.) This puts the user in control and would be no different than getting locked out of any other site out there.

Comment: Third option is good, but when you send an invite link it's better to add a specific link

Comment: @Skrat any reason you recommend not giving the specific link? I think the link would just be a simple "somewebsite.com/reset-password".

Comment: Since sending an email with a password reset link is simpler and avoids the security problems that go with sending people a plaintext randomly generated password, I guess that's the way to go. More views on this welcome!

Comment: @aaravam Sending them a link like that is totally appropriate. I was imagining them receiving the second stage password reset link in the first email that allows them to enter a new password on your site. This would be as insecure as #1.

Answer (score 1):

All the opinions in comments are valid.
We can say that security wise both approach are similar if we assume that for option 1:

- It's one time password stored for a limited period of time and become invalid after a fixed time-slot.
- The user is obliged to change the password at first login.
- Algorithm for password generation is random enough to make it safe against brute force (long enough with special char in it ecc.)

However I would go for option 2 just because it is easier for the user and in terms of development does't add anything, I even found it slightly easier.

But I would suggest is to add an alert consisting in a mail to the user once password has been reset/changed so that user can report case of stolen identity.

**EXTRA STEP IF YOU CAN**

If in your existing data you also hold phone numbers that you could offer a 2 step auth with SMS, but off course this will be more expansive even in terms of plain fees, so it makes sense if you really think you need that level of security.